# Why does Number constructor fail to parse numbers with separators?

Tags: javascript, numbers

Since JavaScript has numeric separators (`_`, `U+005F`), why does `Number("3_0")` return `NaN`? Shouldn't it work like `Number("0x08")` which returns 8?

```js
Number.isNaN(Number("3_0")) // true
Number.isNaN(Number(3_0))   // false
Number("3_0") === 30        // false
Number(3_0) === 30          // true
```

Comment: Likely backwards compatibility, as doing so would potentially break old code. Additionally, it's to be used as visual cue in code, and converting a string to a number doesn't need that (in most cases, why not write the number to begin with?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-tonumber-applied-to-the-string-type), there are a few differences between the syntax accepted for numeric literals and the syntax accepted for a string value when being converted to a numeric value.

One of the differences is

> A StringNumericLiteral cannot include a NumericLiteralSeparator.

If I have to guess, the reason is that accepting such characters would change the behavior of existing valid JavaScript code, which may break working applications.